# Cannot import MaterialTimeControlModule after installation

Tags: angular5, angular6

I am trying to install https://github.com/SteveDunlap13/MaterialTimeControl under Angular 6. The installation succeeds without errors but I still cannot import the `MaterialTimeControlModule`.

All I can see is in my `node_modules/` this is the only directory which is not marked as "orange" so I guess that means there's something wrong?

[image]

What am I missing here or could this be due to my recent update from Angular 5 to Angular 6?

Comment: Oragne? What OS and IDE you use?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Webstorm

Comment: when you go to node_modules using only your OS file explorer do you see material-time-controll directory (with not empy content) ?

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Yes. After installing it via `npm` the directory is there.

Comment: How do you import `MaterialTimeControlModule` ?

Comment: I am following this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-time-control?file=demo%2Fapp.module.ts) example. I add it to my imports in my `app.module.ts`

Comment: As you can see, in that example,ina app.module there is import MaterialTimeControlModule from.... SRC directory (not node_modules) !

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Hm, you're right. Does that mean I have to put the entire path in my import statement?

Comment: this mean that you should create similar `materia-time-control.module.ts` file in your SRC directory and import it in app.module.ts in similar way

Comment: you probably shoud also create similar src/time-control directory... - I will write it as answer

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski So I basically have to copy the `src/` of `material-time-control` into my source code?

Comment: probably yes (maybe you need change it a little to match your particular project configuration like directory structure etc.)

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski Hm, alright that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you write in comments under your question:

> I am following this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-time-control?file=src%2Fmaterial-time-control.module.ts) example. I add it to my imports in my
>   app.module.ts

As you can see, in that example,in `app.module.ts` there is import `MaterialTimeControlModule` from.... SRC directory (not node_modules) !

This mean that you should create similar `materia-time-control.module.ts` file in your SRC directory and import it in `app.module.ts` in similar way. You probably should also create similar `src/time-control` directory (may be with som local changes depend on your particular project).